# convergence in distribution of sum of random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

If $X_{n}$ converges to $X$ in distribution and $Y_{n}$ converges to $Y$ in distribution. Then it is not guaranteed that $X_{n}+Y_{n}$ converges to $X+Y$ in distribution.

I have seen that this is not always true. I have also seen counter examples. But I am having trouble in understanding them.

Example:-

Define $X_{n}=Bern(\frac{1}{2})$ and $Y_{n}=1-X_{n}$.

Then $X_{n}$ converges to $X$ which has $Bern(\frac{1}{2})$ distribution and also

$Y_{n}$ converges to $Y$ which has $Bern(\frac{1}{2})$. Because each $Y_{n}$ has $Bern(\frac{1}{2})$ distribution.

$X_{n}+Y_{n}$ converges to just a random variable $Z$ which takes the value $1$ with probability $1$.

But when I try and figure out what the distribution is for $X+Y$ then I cannot think of how I  should consider the sum. For example can I think of them as independent and look at them as a sum of iid bernoulli $\frac{1}{2}$ in which case it would have a $Binomial(2,\frac{1}{2})$ distribution. But it does not seem right to me as $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ were dependent. How should I go about figuring out the distribution of the sum?

I have also seen another example which is sufficient. But I want to know where I might be mixing up stuff and where my thinking is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same squence $(X_n)$ can conerge to many r.v.s in distribution. So your $X$ and $Y$ are not uniquely defined r.v.s. Their distribution is uniquely defined but the r.v's themselves are not. It is possible that you have $X=Y$ and it is also pssoble that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. So you cannot compute the distribtion of $X+Y$.

Comment: Okay so I cannot conclude anything about the distribution of $X+Y$ right?. I think my broader question is once we have convergence( in d) . Then when we are trying to sum(or rather find the distribution) $X+Y$ . Then is the initial $\omega$ in the sample space which we took to define pointwise convergence of $X_{n}$ to $X$ and $Y_{n}$ to $Y$ relevant?.

Comment: Actually the conept of $X_n \to X$ in distrbution involves only the distributions of $X_n$'s and $X$. It is not even necessary that $X$ is defined on the same space as $(X_n)$. In general you cannot even talk about $X+Y$, much less find its distribution.  @Mr.GandalfSauron

Comment: Okay so for example when I am working with X+Y(knowing that Xn and Yn have converged to X and Y resp.) . Then do I need to keep the distributions of Xn and Yn in the back of my mind. Not that "working" with them would lead me anywhere as you pointed out that we cannot conclude anything about X+Y. Still I want to just clarify things a bit more if I am not annoying you with my stupid questions.